# ¿Como se modifica el texto html mediante js?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy estudiando programación y me piden un código donde a través de botones con `js` se modifique un párrafo.

Busqué como poner el texto en negrita, cursiva y demás pero los métodos que me aparecen por internet aparentemente están obsoletos y no encuentro nada actualizado ni en español ni en inglésx.

Sé que existe `bold()` e `italics()` pero ninguno me funciona, es más en visual studio code me salen tachados, como que estuviesen obsoletos.

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar estaría muy agradecido.

Este es mi código y en el `html` tengo un `<p>` con su respectivo `id` y texto que quiero modificar y botones asociados a sus respectivas funciones que aparecen en la imagen.

```
function LetraEnNegrita(){
    let p=document.getElementById("parrafo");
    p.bold()

}

function cursiva(){
    let p=document.getElementById("parrafo");
    p.italics();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Esas funciones están obsoletas, puedes revisar acá: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_bold.asp

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```js
function LetraEnNegrita(){
    let p=document.getElementById("parrafo");
    p.style.fontWeight ="bold";
}
function cursiva(){
    let p=document.getElementById("parrafo");
    p.style.fontStyle ="italic";
}

function QuitarLetraEnNegrita(){
    let p=document.getElementById("parrafo");
    p.style.fontWeight =null;
}
function Quitarcursiva(){
    let p=document.getElementById("parrafo");
   p.style.fontStyle = null;
}
```

```html
<p id="parrafo">hola</p>

<button onclick="LetraEnNegrita()">Poner Negritas</button>
<button onclick="cursiva()">Poner Curisva</button>

<button onclick="QuitarLetraEnNegrita()">Quitar Negritas</button>
<button onclick="Quitarcursiva()">Quitar Cursiva</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente tienes que añadir p.style eso sirve para dar estilos en JS y luego si quieres poner negrita y cursiva es de la siguiente manera:

```
function LetraEnNegrita(){
    let p=document.getElementById("parrafo");
    p.style.fontWeight ="bold";
}

function cursiva(){
    let p=document.getElementById("parrafo");
    p.style.fontStyle ="italic";
}
```